# Sort pandas df based on constraints

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dummy df.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'car': ['Pickup', 
                           'Racer', 
                           'Lorry',
                           'Luxury',
                           'Cabrio',
                           'Bicycle', 'Truck'],
                   'old_owner': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '1'],
                   'new_owner': ['2', '3', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1']})


print(df)
>>>        
    car     old_owner   new_owner
0   Pickup       1         2
1    Racer       1         3
2    Lorry       1         2
3   Luxury       2         1
4   Cabrio       2         1
5  Bicycle       3         1
6   Truck        1         1
```

The dummy df shows how I reassigned cars. Think of the numbers as account numbers. The numbers could be 14534 or 12131, so pretty random and not just, 1,2,3,4....
Unfortunately, it is not sorted how I want it to be. I reassigned cars either to 1 or "non-1's"
Now I want to sort it such that before I take away a car from non-1's I need to give them one from 1. In other words, non-1's should never have less cars at any moment than they had originally. 1 can have one less car than originally at any moment until 1 got another one assigned.
Sorted based on that I would like the dummy df to end up looking like this:

```
        car     old_owner   new_owner
0    Pickup       1           2
1    Luxury       2           1
2    Racer        1           3
3    Bicycle      3           1
4    Lorry        1           2
5    Cabrio       2           1
6    Truck        1           1
```

Comment: Can you provide some more examples to validate my approach below?

Comment: @mozway ok, will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, and assuming you have the same non-Tims in both columns, you could reorder using a series of sorts:

```
out = (df
   # identify 1s
   .assign(one=lambda d: d['old_owner'].eq('1'),
           loop=lambda d: d['one'] & d['new_owner'].eq('1')
          )
   # sort by name
   .sort_values(by=['loop', 'one', 'old_owner', 'new_owner'])
   # compute position with 1s/non-1s groups
   .assign(idx=lambda d: d.groupby('one').cumcount())
   # sort by position, with 1s first, 1-1 last
   .sort_values(by=['loop', 'idx', 'one'], ascending=[True, True, False])
   .drop(columns=['one', 'idx', 'loop'])
)
```

Output:

```
       car old_owner new_owner
0   Pickup         1         2
3   Luxury         2         1
2    Lorry         1         2
4   Cabrio         2         1
1    Racer         1         3
5  Bicycle         3         1
6    Truck         1         1
```

Comment: Nice. In my original df it first removed like 100 cars from "John" but did not directly assign cars to "John". I would have expected it to remove 1 car from "John" and give him 1 directly afterwards.

Comment: That's why I requested additional examples. As noted, this approach assumes the same count of names in both columns (ideal case) how to handle more generic cases remains to be clarified (with examples) ;)

Comment: right, understood. I checked in my original df now and I have 516 unique names in old_owner and also 516 unique names in new_owner

Comment: I believe I know the issue. I have numbers instead of names in my original df. Instead of Tim I have 12345, instead of Doe I have 56645 and so on...

Comment: sorry for that. I edited the question now. Thanks for bearing with me :)

Comment: @Exa I edited the answer to not rely on the lexicographic order and explicitly pushing 1-1 to the end

Comment: For some reason, in my original df it still does not sort it one by one. In fact, I removed the .drop line and then saw that "one" and "loop" are always False for some reason.

Comment: Did you use the correct type for `1`?

Comment: no, not a single "True" in the whole dataset

Comment: now I think it worked! I removed the "" around the 1 within .eq(1) and now it is as expected. In fact, the 1 is 200293444 in my original df.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255608/discussion-between-exa-and-mozway).

Answer (score 1):

You could approach this problem from a graph perspective.

Here is your graph:

[image]

Now you want to find the [Eulerian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) of the graph (*i.e.* a path that visits each edge exactly once).

Using [`networkx`](https://networkx.org) and [`eulerian_circuit`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.euler.eulerian_circuit.html):

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='old_owner', target='new_owner',
                            edge_attr='car', create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph)

out = pd.DataFrame([[G.edges[e]['car'], *e[:2]] for e in
                     nx.eulerian_circuit(G, keys=True)],
                   columns=['car', 'old_owner', 'new_owner'])
```

Output:

```
       car old_owner new_owner
0    Racer       Tim       Doe
1  Bicycle       Doe       Tim
2    Lorry       Tim      John
3   Cabrio      John       Tim
4   Pickup       Tim      John
5   Luxury      John       Tim
6    Truck       Tim       Tim
```

Comment: Very interesting (both solutions)! Here I am getting the error "networkx.exception.NetworkXError: G is not Eulerian." I guess my dummy example might not reflect all the edge cases in my data. My original df has around 20k rows...

Comment: @Exa, yes this solution assumes that the graph is Eulerian, which means in your case that all nodes have an even number of edges, and an equal number of incoming and outgoing edges.